# how to find next of next day in php

Tags: php, date

I found the next Wednesday which is January 2, and I need to print Thursday(January-3). I used the same method to find the next Thursday, but I am getting 27th of December which is also Thursday. how to use '+1' day in this senario.

```
 $f_date = new DateTime(); 
 $f_date->modify('next wednesday');

 $s_date = new DateTime(); 
 $s_date->modify('next thursday');
```

I tried something like this. but it doesn't work

```
date(strtotime($f_date->modify('next wednesday')->date .' +1 day'))->format('F d');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right, you just need to call `modify()` again:

```
$f_date = new DateTime(); 
$f_date->modify('next wednesday')->modify('+1 day');
echo $f_date->format('F d');
```

Output:

```
January 03
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EhfrP)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$f_date = new DateTime();
$f_date = $f_date->modify('next wednesday');
$f_date->modify('+1 day');
```

Now, you can apply your desired formats

Answer (score -1):

You can use following to return January 3

```
echo date('F d',strtotime('today'. ' +8 day'));
```